# Android Share button does not appear and Material Design not working

Tags: java, android, xml

**Share button does not appear on the action bar**.. Please help..!!
Here is the code::

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Currency;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;


@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1;
ListView l1;
ArrayList<Array_songs> songlist;
EditText e1;
Song_adapter adp;
private ShareActionProvider MenuSAP;

ImageButton ib;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.iconw);

    l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    ib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib1);
    songlist=new ArrayList<Array_songs>();
    e1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e1.addTextChangedListener(tw);

    ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            try{
                startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_OK );
            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException r){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"song cant be played", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    });


    adp=new Song_adapter(MainActivity.this, songlist, this.getApplication());
    l1.setAdapter(adp);
    getSongList("");


    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {

            int sCB = getVar();
            if(sCB == 0) {
                Array_songs slist = songlist.get(position);
                String Song_Title = slist.get_title();
                String Song_Artist = slist.get_artist();
                long Song_ID = slist.get_id();


                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Song_Artist + Song_Title + String.valueOf(Song_ID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Uri song_path = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Song_ID);


                Intent musicplayer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                musicplayer.setDataAndType(song_path, "audio/*");

                try {

                    startActivity(musicplayer);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
    });



    l1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            changeVar();
            vibrate();
            int select = l1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            l1.setItemChecked(select, true);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void vibrate() {
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(120);
}


private void changeVar() {
    ((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).setShowCheckBox(1);
}



private int getVar()
{
    Integer sCB = Integer.parseInt(((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).getShowCheckBox());
    return sCB;
}



TextWatcher tw=new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        songlist.clear();
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getSongList(s.toString());



    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};



protected void  onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, data);

    if(requestcode==REQUEST_OK && resultcode==RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> ls=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        e1.setText(ls.get(0));

    }


}



public void getSongList(String stitle){
    ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
    Uri music=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor mus=cr.query(music, null, null, null, null);

    if(mus != null && mus.moveToFirst()){

        int titleint=mus.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistint= mus.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int songid=mus.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        do{
            String songTitle=mus.getString(titleint);
            String songArtist=mus.getString(artistint);
            long  songId=mus.getLong(songid);

            if(songTitle.toUpperCase().contains(stitle.toUpperCase())){


                songlist.add(new Array_songs(songId, songTitle, songArtist));

            }

        }while(mus.moveToNext());

    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    MenuSAP = new ShareActionProvider(this);
    MenuSAP.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, MenuSAP);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,"audio/*");
    return shareIntent;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int check;
    check = getVar();
    if(check == 1)
    {
        ((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).setShowCheckBox(0);
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
}
```

SongAdapter.java

```
public class Song_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Array_songs> song_ob;
private LayoutInflater inflator_ob;
private Application xyz;
//private int sCB = ((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
public Song_adapter(Context c,ArrayList<Array_songs> songlist, Application a)
{
    song_ob=songlist;
    inflator_ob= LayoutInflater.from(c);
    xyz = a;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return song_ob.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinearLayout lin_ob =(LinearLayout)inflator_ob.inflate(R.layout.song_content, parent,false) ;
    Array_songs ars_ob= song_ob.get(position);
    TextView title= (TextView)lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
    TextView artist= (TextView)lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.artist);
    //CheckBox check = (CheckBox) lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.cbselect);
    if(((SyncClass) xyz).getShowCheckBox() == "1")
    {
        lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.cbselect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.cbselect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    String stitle= ars_ob.get_title();
    String sartist= ars_ob.get_artist();

    title.setText(stitle);
    artist.setText(sartist);


    return lin_ob;

}

}
```

SyncClass.java

```
public class SyncClass extends Application {
private String showCheckBox = "0";

public String getShowCheckBox()
{
    return showCheckBox;
}

public void setShowCheckBox(int showCheckBox)
{
    this.showCheckBox = Integer.toString(showCheckBox);
}
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      tools:context=".MainActivity"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Also **i want to apply the material design** theme to my project.. and i have done the following:-

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.musicginni" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconw"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:name=".SyncClass">
    <activity
        android:name=".StartUp"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

this is the styles.xml(v21) file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff95609b</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#ff644469</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff8f7ec</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#ff403a25</item>
</style>
<color name="custom_theme_color">#ffffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Styles.xml file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:absListViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff774d7d</item>
</style>
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">#ffb3aac6</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

The material design was working fine before i compiled the appcompat v7 library and used ActionBarActivity instead of Activity..

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"    />
```

And:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    ShareActionProvider MenuSAP = (ShareActionProvider)  MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    MenuSAP.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And if you using `progaurd` you need this:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider { *; }
```

**Edit**
Try this:

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    new ShareActionProvider(this).setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when i run this code **it gives the following exception**
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference`

**Also in menu_main.xml**
`android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"`
gives the error as 
`android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider is not assignable to android.view.ActionProvider`

Comment: The **xml works fine but still there is null pointer error** at the same line of code.

Comment: Are you sure that you changed in xml to  app:actionProviderClass? you must use the app prefix. the error android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider is not assignable to android.view.ActionProvider say it not thw right one.

Comment: yes am absolutely sure about that.. XML works fine now.. The java statement still gives the null pointer error...

Comment: The code runs without any exception **but the share button still does not appear**

Comment: change     app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
 to "always" maybe it will help

Comment: Even that doesn't help..!

Comment: try to remove  actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.iconw);
. If won't help try to remove toolbar. very easy to use and setup

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the following steps

1. If your activity extends from AppCompatActivity, you have to change on the
   menu_main.xml the item that must begin with app:showAsActio...or app:actionProvider etc.
2. You must import the correct (import:android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider)...
3. And on the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` (Menu menuItem) you have to attribute the value `MenuItemCompat.getActioProvider(menuItem)` instead of just `menuItem(getActionProvider)`.

Comment: You should read ways to format your answer - and make better use of the preview function. As is, your input is close to unreadable.